# Error installing Sudo on Debian

Tags: debian, sudo, sudoers

I'm trying to install `sudo` on Debian.
At first I logged as root and then `apt-get install sudo` when I open `nano /etc/sudoers` it is an empty file.

Here is a screenshot of my `apt-get install sudo`. Does someone know what those errors mean?

[image: screenshot]

I tried `apt-get install`and `apt install`

[Apt install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEt3y.png)

Comment: These errors are to do with resolving DNS records - specifically `ftp.pt.debian.org`. The package was not installed.
Does your computer have DNS configured correctly, and can you query the servers and get a response using `nslookup` or `dig`?

Comment: Im using Virtual Box and i just installed debian, so i guess yes. I didnt change anything. I will be honest, i dont really know what you are asking me about.

Comment: Also, don't edit `sudoers` manually. Use the `visudo` command instead. Lack of this command should be a hint that the package wasn't installed correctly. And next time please don't post screenshots of text. They are harder to read, can't be zoomed in, aren't readable for screen readers and can't be indexed by Google.

Comment: What happens if you run `nslookup ftp.pt.debian.org`? Please include the output in your question. Have you tried `apt update`?

Comment: `nslookup: command not found`. Yes, i tried `apt update` and `apt-get update`. Both show the same errors as before.

Comment: Does the virtual machine have a network interface that is configured and working? `ifconfig -a` and `cat /etc/resolve.conf` might shed more light...

Comment: Try something simple like `ping debian.org` to make sure you can do a basic name lookup and internet access first.   If not it could be the Virtual Box networking incorrectly setup.

Comment: `ifconfig: command not found` and `cat: /etc/resolve.conf: no such file or directory`. i dont have nslookup installed. `ping: fpt.pt.debian.org: temporary failure in name resolution`